# How to poll the username, when having the UID?

Tags: ldap, nsswitch.conf, sssd

we're using ldap with sssd for the usermanagement, so our users are not in the "/etc/passwd"

Unfortunately, ps just shows the UIDs:

```
[root@xyz ~]# id jmw
uid=1582(jmw) gid=1582(jmw) groups=1582(jmw), 1000(admins)

[root@xyz ~]# ps aux
[..cutting some output..]
1582      26794 25.0  0.4 190420 38508 ?        S    12:15   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -c php.ini
[..cutting some output..]
```

How can i poll the username, that belongs to a UID? ( a `grep ':1582:' /etc/passwd` doesn't work ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `getent`:

```
getent passwd 1582
```

That'll look up entries via your configured nss config.  If you've configured it to use LDAP, then it'll use LDAP.